# VSCode ignores cpp standard when folder is opened in WSL: Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open a folder with WSL: Ubuntu and then try to build the project it seems to ignore the cpp standard set in VSCode's User settings. I can choose the standard I want by configuring a task.json file however I want to know how to change the default cpp standard for any folder opened in VSCode with WSL: Ubuntu. I have tried adding the following in my User settings in VSCode.

```
...
"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
...
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  ...
  "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
  ...
},
```

And yet when I build the following and execute the output I get `201402` indicating it is using c++14.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to change the default c++ standard?

It seems that if I open the file in windows then it works fine as well so I don't know what the difference is here?

Comment: iirc by settings you just tell which version of standard should intellisense work with. Actual compiler flags are specified in the `.vscode/task.json` file or controlled by CMake if you build your project with CMake extensions

Comment: Ok actually maybe you're right. I think I got confused and c++17 was just the default standard for the version of g++ I had installed on windows but changing it in the settings isn't actually changing the standard for the compiler in windows either.

I don't suppose there is a way to change how the task.json is generated so that it always specifies some particular compiler flags?